# Installation Ruby failed

Tags: ruby

I tried to install Ruby 2.3.1. When I type `sudo make` after `sudo ./configure`
I get this error:

```
executable host ruby is required. use --with-baseruby option. uncommon.mk:803:
recipe for target 'id.h' failed
make: *** [id.h] Error 1
```

Can someone help me?

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SJP1O.png)

Comment: use rvm to install manage multiple version of ruby

Comment: Can you please copy the command you tried to run and the whole error message into your question. The screenshot is almost unreadable.

Comment: command : sudo ./configure
                   sudo make

Answer (score 0):

[RVM](https://rvm.io/rvm/install) is one of the best ways for managing ruby versions.

To install and use Ruby 2.3.1, just run:

`rvm install ruby-2.3.1` followed by `rvm use ruby-2.3.1`

A quick version check should reveal something similar to:

```
$ ruby -v
ruby 2.3.1p112
```